# Merge two CSS and find colliding properties using WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm

I have two CSS from two big projects, whereas I need to merge the two CSS together. Essentially, I just included both CSS in the HTML header of the new project that needs both CSS.

Using WebStorm what is the best way to find and track colliding CSS properties?

For example (note this is just a basic example to express my point):

**first.css**

```
.my-class-1 {
    background: #eeeeee;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
    min-height: 59%;
}
```

**second.css**

```
.my-class-2 {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

And given that it is used

`<div class="my-class-1 my-class-2" ></div>`

From these examples, the `background` and `min-height` properties are *colliding* to each other.

Comment: There is no way, you have to do this manually. There are too many cases to consider. Maybe it's better to just start new?

Comment: You could inspect the element and see which styles are crossed out (means the are over-ridden in the other class, ie they "collide")

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to actually load the page in your browser, and use **chrome dev tools** to inspect the styles. You can do this with most browsers, but I would choose either **Chrome** or **Firefox** as they're probably the most refined. This can show you the computed styles and what styles are overwritten by others.

You need to check for these styles manually as your IDE won't have the context to understand that there are conflicting classes being used in the html.

However, if you want to search for *duplicate* CSS within the CSS file, I would suggest something like http://csslint.net/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use https://stylelint.io/

With this configuration:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
  "rules": {
    "no-duplicate-selectors":  true
  }
}
```

It is able to detect similar names which actually help (mostly) finding the colliding CSS properties based on common names.